# Switch between users in an upstart script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, upstart

Is it possible to have a upstart script that runs the pre-script as root but the rest as `normal_user`. I'm trying something like:

```
setuid normal_user

pre-start exec su -c "echo I'm root" root

script
exec /bin/bash <<"EOT"
    echo "haha, I'm normal user"
EOT
```

Is it necessary to drop setuid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working by removing `setuid normal_user` and change

```
exec /bin/bash <<"EOT"
```

to

```
exec sudo -u normal_user /bin/bash <<"EOT"
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you will have to remove the `setuid` stanza so that your job runs as root. You can then drop privileges in the `exec`/`script` stanza.

From the Upstart Cookbook's [Changing User](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#changing-user) section:

> The recommended method for Debian and Ubuntu systems is to use the helper utility start-stop-daemon(8) like this:
>   `exec start-stop-daemon --start -c myuser --exec command`
>
> If you want to use su(1)... To avoid the fork(2) caused by the shell being spawned, you could instead specify:
>   `exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' $user -- /path/to/command --arg1=foo -b wibble`
>
> A basic example using sudo(8):
>   `exec sudo -u $user command`