# changing user in upstart script

Tags: bash, sudo, upstart

I have an upstart script that does some logging tasks. The script **testjob.conf** looks like below:

```
description "Start Logging"
start on runlevel [2345]

script
  sudo -u user_name echo Test Job ran at  `date` >> /home/user_name/Desktop/jobs.log
end script
```

Then I run the script with `sudo service testjob start` and I get `testjob stop/waiting` as result. The file jobs.log is created and the logging is done. However the file is owned by root. I wanted to change this and hence added `sudo -u user_name` part infront of the command mentioned in [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412554/switch-between-users-in-an-upstart-script%20*this%20similar%20post*).

However this doesnot seem to do the trick. Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log file is created by the `>>` indirection which runs in the context of the root shell that also starts `sudo`.

Try making the process that `sudo` starts create the file, for instance with:

```
sudo -u user_name sh -c 'echo Test Job ran at  `date` >> /home/user_name/Desktop/jobs.log'
```

In this case the `sh` running as `user_name` will "execute" the `>>` indirection.

Comment: This solved it but when I try `sudo service testjob stop`, I get `stop: Unknown instance: `. I feel like this because service exits after writing to the log file. Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: Sure, just don't exit. I don't know what you intend to do, but in your example you could add `; sleep 99999999` after `echo`, like: `sudo -u user_name sh -c 'echo Test Job ran at  \`date\` >> /home/user_name/Desktop/jobs.log; sleep 99999999'`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! :)